# How can i pass a secure/sensitive string from my back (nodejs) to my front (angular) hidden from user?

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, api, dotenv

I am currently working on a project composed by:
Front: Angular ; Back: NodeJS

The backend compiles angular static files with the command: `response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dirname', 'index.html'));`

I have stored my API keys into my backend using dotenv. Then, when i start (in main.ts file) my Angular app, i do an API call to my back to get these API keys. But the response is visible from user POV, so i encrypted it. But now, I have to hide the encryption key. That's the string I want to pass from my back to my front.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: What kind of API keys do you try to hide? The ones for your own API? Why would you try to do that? API keys for a third party API like, e. g. Google? In general: you cannot hide information that is sent to the client from the user because the code is available at the client and can be reengineered. If you MUST hide third party API keys ultimately, the only chance you have is to build a server side proxy for those third party APIs.

Comment: I have to hide API keys from GCP, Stripe and SendInBlue. But, those for GCP are also protected with CORS, they are only available from my domain so its ok. But Stripe and SendInBlue dont provide this security... So I absolutely need to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide such information from a very experienced and determined user / attacker. All types of obfuscation can be broken because your code for de-obfuscation / decryption will run at the client side and can thus be re-enigeered, as I already stated in my comment.

To be safe you should build a proxy layer for the unprotectable keys (SendInBlue, Stripe). The proxy can be built quite lightweight by using the same routes as the actual APIs extended by some prefix like, e.g. `/sendinblue`. This way you can use a single request handler and just add the authorization information (code not tested, just a hint):

```js
const axios = require('axios');

app.get('/sendinblue/:remainder', (request, response, next) => {
  // I am not sure, if this takes the whole remainder or just until
  // the next slash /
  // If not you have to parse the url-attribute of the request object
  let originalurl = request.params.remainder;

  axios.get(sendinblueBaseUrl + '/' + originalurl, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': // API key here
    }
  })
  .then(result => {
     response.send(result);
  });
});
```

The code can be reduced even more by using axios interceptors.

I know, that is not satisfying but frustrating. Nonetheless, you should not try to implement some amateurish (no offense!) encryption or obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! It will be VERY useful for me. Have a great time ;)